# API queries in Nodejs/Express

Tags: node.js, express

why doesn't this work?

```
/search?name=:name
```

but this works :

```
/search/name=:name
```

how to make the former work with the `?` (Question mark)

Comment: The text after the `?` is probably not considered a part of the URL by the router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

> Query strings are not part of the route path.

If you want to use the query string, use `req.query`:

```
app.get('/search', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.query);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is either route parameters:

```
app.get('/foo/:bar', (req, res) => { //GET /foo/helloworld
    console.log(req.params.bar);     //helloworld
    //...
});
```

Or GET parameters:

```
app.get('/foo', (req, res) => {  //GET /foo?bar=helloworld
    console.log(req.query.bar);  //helloworld
    //...
});
```

What you are doing right now is mixing them up, which doesn't work.